# How to remove a DNS nameserver on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, dns

So I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Firefox has been incredibly slow, and I suspect my DNS settings to be the issue.

When I do a `cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` here is what I get:

```
nameserver 106.186.17.181
nameserver 118.88.20.195
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

(My router also has `106.186.17.181` and `118.88.20.195` for the DNS.)
For troubleshooting purpose, I'd like to remove the `nameserver 127.0.1.1`, but cannot figure out where/how to do that.

If I do a search for it, here are the files where it appears:

```
/etc/hosts:127.0.1.1    bidule
/etc/resolv.conf:nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Where is this 127.0.1.1 getting generated from?
How can I remove it?

I don't often tweak my settings, so excuse me if I am asking something that should be obvious. I did try to look for an answer online, but found nothing conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be closed. I resolved my issue.

The DNS was indeed the cause of my slow internet, but it had to be modified on the router, not my laptop.